# How to put the section line into tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, xparse, titletoc

The contents of chapter are put into tcolor by below code.
How can we modify the code for section.
My code have created the `\mysectionnamebox` to add a contentline of section.
Thank you for help!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,intersections,shapes.geometric,arrows,decorations.markings,arrows.meta,patterns.meta,patterns}

\definecolor{darkmidnightblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.4}
\newtcolorbox{chapternamebox}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  valign=center,
  interior style={left color={darkmidnightblue!30!darkmidnightblue},
  right color={darkmidnightblue!90!darkmidnightblue}},
  colframe={white},
  boxrule={1pt},
  colupper={white},
  size=small,
  boxsep=2pt,
  sharp corners,
  fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large},
  nobeforeafter,
  equal height group=chaptertoc,
  left=0.25cm,
  overlay={
    \path (frame.north west) coordinate (A)
        (frame.south west) coordinate (B)
        ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) coordinate (O)
        ($(O)!1!90:(B)$) coordinate (C);
    \draw[thick,white] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
  }
  #1,
}


\newtcolorbox{sectionnamebox}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colframe={white},
  boxrule={1pt},
  size=small,
  boxsep=3pt,
  sharp corners,
  colback=yellow!15,
  sidebyside,
  sidebyside align=center,
  bicolor,
  righthand width=1.25cm,
  colbacklower=cyan!25,
  fontupper={\sffamily},
  nobeforeafter,
  #1,
}

\newcommand{\mychapternamebox}[3][]{%
  \begin{chapternamebox}[#1]
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.75\linewidth}}
        #2&#3%
  \end{tabular}
  \end{chapternamebox}%
}

\newcommand{\mysectionnamebox}[3][]{%
  \begin{sectionnamebox}[#1]
        #2 
      \tcblower
      \begin{flushright}
      #3
      \end{flushright}
  \end{sectionnamebox}%
}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\mychapternamebox[width=\linewidth]{\protect\chaptername{} \thechapter}{#1}}%%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%
}{}{}


\xpatchcmd{\@section}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}%
  {\protect\numberline{\section}#1}%
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{section}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\mysectionnamebox[width=\linewidth]{\protect\thesection. #1}{\thepage}}%%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{section}}%
}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}

\mysectionnamebox{A}{B}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\mysectionnamebox[width=\linewidth]{\protect\thesection. First Section}{\thepage}}%%
\section{Second Section}

\chapter*{Third Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]